# UnicodeDecodeError when runvsever Django

Tags: django, database, postgresql

Have a problem when starting local django server. When trying to run:
`python manage.py runserver` or `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080`
an error occurs:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 55: invalid continuation byte
```

Full error log:

```
(my_env) D:\mysite\>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^article/(?P<pk>\d+)/bookmark/$' [name='article_bookmark'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().

System check identified 9 issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 574, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user_brad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 55: invalid continuation byte
```

I looked at previous answers where it was recommended to change the Windows username. I changed - did not help. Please, help.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Python version 3.11.5 
Django version 4.2.4
PostgreSQL 15.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit (1 ёЄЁюър)

**(1 ёЄЁюър)** - when installing get postgres version SELECT version();*

Comment: What are the database connection settings? Looks like that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @AKX  DATABASES = {
    'default':  {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dabase-new',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
          'OPTIONS': {
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
        },
    }
}

Comment: @AKX It is worth noting that if I remove the name of the database, then the server starts, but an error occurs when rendering:

settings. DATABASES are configured incorrectly. Specify a value of NAME or OPTIONS['service'].

Comment: Check if your database encoding is set to utf-8, you can check using this query `SELECT datname, pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'your_db_name';`, if it isn’t, then you should create another database with utf-8 and migrate your data